# Questions about Functions

Tags: functions

The function $f$ is defined by $f(x)=\frac{(m+x)}{(2+3x)}$ for all values of $x$ except when $x=h$ and $m$ is a constant. Given that value of $1$ is unchanged under this mapping, how should I find the value of $m$?

Comment: @KushalBhuyan: I re-added the dollar signs around "m" and "1" because all mathematics should be set in math-mode. (I also added them around $f$ at the start of the first sentence.) Does that make sense?

Comment: @JohnHughes Yes thank you. It does make sense.

Comment: You recieved 2 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, you should upvote all the useful answers and accept the answer that is most useful to you.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

The sentence

> The value of $1$ is unchanged under this mapping

translates into the equation $$f(1)=1.$$

Answer (score 2):

$f(1)=\frac{m+1}{2+3}=1 \iff m+1=5 \iff m=4.$